# Regex doesn't rules out cases python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, ocr

I'm trying to develop a regex where it will take in format i.e:

```
date: 1:10 #7 (correct)
date: 1:10 (correct)
1:10 #7 (correct)
13.01.06 (incorrect)
```

Here is my regex developed on pythex:

```
(date)? ?\D? ?(1|4) ?(:|-|\.) ?[-+]?[0-9]+( ?(#) ?[a-zA-Z0-9]?)?
```

[image]

I'm working in python projects that uses OCR so sometimes the ":" between 1 and 10 is not translated correctly. Do you guys have a better way to tackle to regex problem?

Comment: Does this work (date)? ?\D:? ?(1|4) ?(:|-|.) ?[-+]?[0-9]+( ?(#) ?[a-zA-Z0-9]?)?

Comment: Yes, this works!!! How did you figure it out?

Comment: you can put fixed in-place chars to match in regex. I felt that you need : in all your strings so it should be mandatory char in expression . When you put : after D it means after digits there must be matching :, if not regex match will fail. That is the reason first string is not matching.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need regex? If not, you could solve your problem by parsing the string to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html).

```
from datetime import datetime
def test_date(date_string):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d.%m.%y')
        return # or do something else to skip the further processing
    except ValueError:
        pass
    # Process valid date string
    print('Valid date: {}'.format(date_string))

test_date('13.01.06') # Does not print anything
test_date('1:10 #7')  # Works!
```

Comment: yes, as I mentioned, I'm working with OCR to translate pdf into txt, this is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the non-digit pattern obligatory by removing `?` after `\D` and wrap the whole part before the `(1|4)` pattern with an optional non-capturing group (to match `date`, `:` and space optionally), and in the end add a word boundary before the `(1|4)` pattern so that it could only be matched as a whole word, when the digit is not preceded with a digit, letter or `_`.

```
(?:(date)? ?\D ?)?\b([14]) ?([-:.]) ?[-+]?([0-9]+)( ?# ?([a-zA-Z0-9]*))?
^^^           ^  ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/atEff6/1/).